# Evitar a última ocorrência de caractere concatenado em um loop

Tags: php

A dúvida é a seguinte, se tenho um foreach ou qual;quer outra estrutura de repetição que recebe dados da tabela e exibe as categorias:

```
foreach ($categories as $c){
            $c.nome . ' - ';
    }
```

supondo que esse código fosse exibir como resultado:

```
Categoria_1 - Categoria_2 - Categoria_3 -
```

Como fazer para que  esse "-" não apareça após a última repetição do laço, como oculta-lo?

A minha intenção é que ao invés de exibir como mostrado a cima o resultado final seja:

```
Categoria_1 - Categoria_2 - Categoria_3
```

com o "-" não aparecendo nem no início nem no final, mas somente entre os nomes das categorias.

Comment: `$c.nome` seria `$c->nome`? O `$c` é um objeto?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Utilize a função [implode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php):

```
$categorias = array("Categoria 1","Categoria 2", "Categoria 3");
$lista = implode(" - ", $categorias);
```

**Atualização**:

Para objetos utilizei o [array_map](http://php.net/array_map) para retorna apenas a propriedade `nome`:

```
$nomes = array_map(function($objeto) { return $objeto->nome; }, $categorias);
$lista = implode(" - ", $nomes);
```

Veja exemplo funcionando no [ideone](https://ideone.com/IcmlpY)

Comment: é isso, deu certo, exatamente oque eu queria fazer :)

Comment: Lucio: dá para fazer _join_ com `$categorias.nome`? uma array simples dá como no teu exemplo (e nesse caso acho mesmo a melhor opção) mas se a funcionalidade desejada for concatenar/join de propriedades de um objeto então falta algo na tua solução, certo? (um mapeamento da array inicial para outra array com as propriedades que devem ser concatenadas)

Comment: @Sergio, editei a resposta, veja se é isso

Comment: @luciorubeens boa! `+1`

Comment: luciorubeens, você é um gênio, man

Answer (score 4):

Para isso podes encurtar a *string* final usando

```
$string = substr($string, 0, -3); // aqui digo para retirar os ultimos 3 caracteres
// ou 
$string = rtrim($string, ' - ');  // aqui digo para retirar a string " - " da string inicial
```

Repara que no teu loop não estás a concatenar corretamente, deves ter

```
$string.= $c -> nome.' - ';
```

O que está em falta é a variável `$string`, o operador de concatenação `.=` e a maneira como acedes à propriedade do objeto que deve ser `->` e não `.`.

Comment: Sergio o - eu que coloco como vc pode ver no exemplo lá do foreach, esse exemplo funciona e exibe da forma que coloquei la em cima, eu queria um divisor entre o nome das categorias só que ele repete esse divisor que no caso eu escolhi "-" no final, então esse caractere não vem em $categoria e sim está como uma string dentro do loop

Answer (score 3):

Pode fazer assim

```
foreach ($c as $categories){
          $categoria.= $c.nome.' - ';
    }
$string = strlen($categoria);

$categories = substr($categoria,0, $string-1);
```

Teste e diga alguma coisa

Comment: Cesar o "-" eu que coloco como vc pode ver no exemplo lá do foreach, esse exemplo funciona e exibe da forma que coloquei la em cima, eu queria um divisor entre o nome das categorias só que ele repete esse divisor que no caso eu escolhi "-" no final, então esse caractere não vem em $categoria e sim está como uma string dentro do loop

Comment: Eu editei agora teste dessa forma e diga o resultado

Comment: utilizando a função implode eu consegui fazer da forma que desejava, foi até mais simples n precisou nem de foreach

Comment: Ok já pode ver sim dessa forma também resolve mas como mencionou o foreach estava ajudando dessa forma.

Comment: sim, vou verificar todas sugeridas e em breve dou o feedback, agradeço a atenção :)

Comment: nada sempre as ordens